# where should I store personal data for npm package?

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-cli

For example, I have a npm package which is a cli-tool. Users should set their yahoo email and password first before using the functionalities.
My question is where should I store the personal data? Is there a convention?

Answer (score 0):

Most cli's use a hidden configuration file commonly stored in the home directory of the user. For example `.cli-config`, it is also good to store the configuration data as JSON or YAML.

Finally be carful to save sensitive data in the config file as it still is just a file and can be accessed by anyone with correct permissions.